# simplify java stream to return an error message

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Hi I am new to stream in java I am trying to find which item inside a file has more than 12 of length also if that item has letters mixed in it and wanted to know if this can be simplified using stream in java without using the forEach method in java stream:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)

stream.forEach(item -> {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(item);
      if (item.length() > 12) {
             log.error("Item must not exceed 12 numbers {}", item);
             streamMessage.set("Item must not exceed 12 numbers");
      }
      else if (matcher.matches()) {
             log.error("Invalid Item format {}", item);
             streamMessage.set("Invalid Item format");
      }
});
```

I also need it to return the log.error messages and the stream message thank you

EDIT:

I have tried Glare storm's answer but the message being returned by this:

```
Stream<String> lengthStream =
                    stream.filter(item -> item.length() > 12);

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

Stream<String> letterStream =
                    lengthStream.filter(pattern.asPredicate());
if(lengthStream != null){
       log.error("Item must not exceed 12 numbers");
       message = "Item must not exceed 12 numbers";
}
if(letterStream != null){
       log.error("Invalid Item format");
       message = "Invalid Item format";
}
```

it always return Invalid Item format even tho there are no letters inside the file and only has exceeded 12 in length

Comment: Stream<String> longNames = stream .filter(str -> str.length() > 12);

Comment: @GlareStorm how about the regex check if it has letters in it the else if block

Comment: Are you trying to do anything with these items other than log messages? Streams are supposed to produce an output value. If you just want to consume them, that's what `forEach()` is for.

Comment: @shmosel my colleague told me not to use forEach()

Comment: @Cedrix Cedrix ; they might have told you not to use it because a stream() is actually takes more memory and more time than a normal for loop; because under the hood thats that is being used if your use a forEach()

Comment: ... your message is being set to Invalid Item format, because the trigger condition is identical to the one before.... so it gets set last....

Comment: `filter` is not a terminal operation, so the stream of the second code example does not do anything. It always returns a new stream; nobody ever said that you can use a `null` check on the result. Generally, if your problem is not solved, don’t accept an answer that doesn’t solve the problem. Most readers will assume that the question’s problem has been solved when an answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter method:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);
Stream<String> filteredStream= stream .filter(str -> str.length() > 12);      

Stream<String> matching = filteredStream.filter(str -> Pattern.matches(regex, str));
```

or:

```
Stream<String> matching = filteredStream.filter(str -> {
      if(str.length() > 12 && Pattern.matches(regex, str))
          return true;
      return false;
     });
```

To set error messages you prolly will have to throw an error that will return what ever message you want:

```
try{
Stream<String> matching = filteredStream.filter(str -> {
      if(str.length() > 11 )
           throw new Exception("Item must not exceed 12 numbers");
      if(Pattern.matches(regex, str))
          return true;
      throw new Exception("Invalid Item format");         
     });
}
catch(Exception e){
   log.error(e);
   message = e;
}
```

Comment: `asPredicate()` calls `find()`, not `matches()`.

Comment: @shmosel rite , thanx i had to google the exact difference to find what was wrong with that, changed my answer accordingly

Comment: @Glare Storm I wanted also to return the error message regarding that

Comment: @GlareStorm also there is no matches method in pattern

Comment: @GlareStorm filteredStream returns no value if it didn't find any items in the stream that has more than 12 in length so there is no value being passed in matching

Comment: @Cedrix Cedrix  sry i missed that cuz i added that in later, edited the answer check this

Comment: @Cedrix Cedrix 
also note that streams dont give error messages and stuff theyre for just streaming output; so might have to keep the one in your answer

Comment: There is no point in writing `str -> { if(condition) return true;    return false; }` like in your second example, instead of just `str -> condition`. Further, chaining `filter` to a stream without a terminal operation has no effect at all. Most relevant for the last example, where it is clear that no other operation has been chained within the `try` block.